# Running iterative formula for n items in array

Tags: excel, vba

I have an array that has a large and variable set of data in Column C and a formula that identifies local peaks/troughs in Column B (minima/maxima effectively; formula is `IF((C5>C4)*(C5>C6),"peak",IF((C5<C4)*(C5<C6),"trough",""))`).

I am looking for a way to calculate the percentage change in various peak-to-trough and trough-to-peak segments in the data set. These segments are variable in range. Any ideas on an efficient and repeatable way of doing this? (Need to potentially do this for multiple independent data sets)

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a performance question?

You will get better performance if you read the ranges into arrays, run the calculations in VBA, and then write the array back into a range. See the link below.

```
Dim Arr() As Variant ' declare an unallocated array.
Arr = Range("A1:C5")' Arr is now an allocated array
```

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx